# vb .net, existing property (eg. backcolor) into custom category

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a component which use BackColor original property and I want to see it grouped with my custom category. How can I do that?

I tried to define my own named BackgroundColor and worked (which of course I was able to insert into my owb category), but when I hide original BackColor redundant property with decoration

[Browsable(False)]

function to set color of my background not worked anymore. I thought [Browsable(False)] just hides the property from designer but in fact will disable subsequent function completely.

So, how can I just group some existing original property into my own category ?

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 6):

> I thought [Browsable(False)] just hides the property from designer but in fact will disable subsequent function completely.

You hid your own property with that attribute.  You must use the Shadows keyword in the property declaration to tell the compiler that you intentionally want to hide the base class property.  A boiler-plate control implementation would look like this:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyControl
    Inherits Control

    <Category("Aardvark")> _
    Public Shadows Property BackColor() As Color
        Get
            Return MyBase.BackColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            MyBase.BackColor = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Which makes the categorized view of the Property window look like this:

[image]